# Rename tag: proj.4 to proj

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Recently the familiar projection library [PROJ](http://proj4.org/) incremented the major version number from 4 to 5, as described in the [NEWS file](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/75976f5d7ed7a5ab4eacbde347925613f416f518/NEWS#L46-L79). Version 4 of this software is popularly known as PROJ.4, however newer releases will use it's original name, PROJ.

(The name of the organizing project remains as proj.4, I think mostly because http://proj.org is not available).

The issue on GIS.se is that the current tag is [proj.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj.4). I suggest renaming it to [proj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj) to be version independent (keeping [proj.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj.4) as a synonym). Also, to be inline with Stack Overflow's [`proj`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/proj) tag, which is equivalent.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Do you have thoughts on whether the [tag:proj4js] tag needs modification too?

Comment: @PolyGeo as far as I can tell, no other related projects with "4" in them have been renamed.

Comment: There are some historical but not significant reasons for the proj.4 distinction. Using proj as the name now that 5.0.0 has come out is sensible.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the vote on this question (that includes a clear proposal) standing at 6-0, and attracting no dissenting answers or comments, I have renamed the [proj.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj.4) tag to [proj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj) leaving [proj.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj.4) as a synonym.

I've done this quickly because the way forward seems clearcut and, even if later dissent does emerge that makes that call appear hasty, it is something that can easily be backed out.